# Создание нейросети с помощью пакета Matlab

Tags: matlab, нейронные-сети

Всем привет!)
Ребята, помогите советом и примером пожалуйста =))

Разбираюсь с нейросетями в матлаб. "Проектирую" вручную, вот код:

```
function net = myNET()

INP =[];  %входной вектор
OUTP = []; %выходной вектор
k=1;
for i=-1.5:0.1:1.5   
    INP(k)= i;
    OUTP(k)=sin(i);   %хочу обучить сеть для вычисления синуса.. просто для понятия того, как это вообще делается =)
    k=k+1;
end

net= newff(INP,OUTP,10);
net= train(net,INP,OUTP);
net.trainParam.epochs = 1200;
net.trainParam.show = 25;
```

После этого в Command Window делаю следующее:

```
 a= myNET
```

Тут высветились параметры НС. Далее ввожу:

```
>> b= sim(myNET,1) % т.е вычисление значения в точке "1", я правильно понял!?)
```

Результат:

> b = 0.8117

Совсем неправильно получается((

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я не прав и как исправить можно? =)
Заранее очень благодарен!

p.s. В качестве примера юзал: http://freestee.ru/index.php/programming/neuralnetworks/10-matlabgreenwave?format=pdf

Answer (score 1):

Я не помню точно матлабовского тулбокса, поправьте если ошибся - вы создаете многослойный персептрон с 10 нейронами в скрытом слое. Что-то мне по приведенному отрывку кажется, что вы сначала тренируете сеть с параметрами по умолчанию (сколько там эпох - 100, 10?), а потом уже их настраиваете, может не хватить времени тренировки. Вечером посмотрю как я сам это делал, может ещё чего увижу.
Ну и просто в качестве совета- кусок

```
for i=-1.5:0.1:1.5   
    INP(k)= i;
    OUTP(k)=sin(i);   %хочу обучить сеть для вычисления синуса.. просто для понятия того, как это вообще делается =)
    k=k+1;
end
```

Лучше заменить на  следующий, это намного быстрее из-за специфики матлаба

```
INP=-1.5:0.1:1.5; 
OUTP=sin(INP);
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за советы! В Матлаб я совсем новичек =) Поэтому рад каждой маленькой критике =) 
 Буду очень Вам признателен, если вечером найдете минутку, чтобы вспомнить как Вы это делали =)

Comment: Освежил память-вы неправильно вызываете функцию создания нейронной сети. она вызывается с параметрами входа (массив размерностью в количество входов на 2, в первой колонке минимальное значение входа, во второй максимальное) и параметрами слоев(вектор строка с количеством нейронов в i-ом слое, последний слой выходной, число нейронов совпадает с выходом). Есть ещё дополнительные параметры. Как ведет себя функция при вашем вызове и что она там создает я не представляю. Таким образом, вам надо поменять создание функции на net= newff([-5 5],[10 1]); Ну и не забудьте переставить настройку тренировк